# Array of concatenated strings into Dictionary<int, int>

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of strings.  Each string is two numbers separated with a "|".

How can I get this array of string into `Dictionary<int,int>` without looping through the array, splitting each string and adding to the dictionary.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply,

```
var result = strings
    .Select(s => s.Split('|'))
    .ToDictionary(a => int.Parse(a[0]), a => int.Parse(a[1]));
```

if duplicates are allowed,

```
var result = strings
    .Select(s => s.Split('|'))
    .ToLookup(a => int.Parse(a[0]), a => int.Parse(a[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToDictionary` method:

```
var dictionary = stringArray.ToDictionary(x => x.Split('|')[0], x => x.Split('|')[1]);
```

But you should be aware that this will throw an exception if there are duplicate keys.

Comment: of course, it's extremely obvious when the answer is in front of you... thanks

Comment: why split it twice, its wastefull